# Accumulate count of list's within another list

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Currently i have code like below. A list embedded with in another list, and i want to get the total count of the embedded list objects.

I want to write a quick oneliner for this. Is there an efficient Lambda or FP trick i can do in Java 8?

```
int totalNo = 0;
for (ClassB classB : listOfClassB) {
    totalNo+= classB.getAnotherObjList().size();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
long totalSum = listOfClassB.stream()
     .mapToInt(elem -> elem.getAnotherObjList().size())
     .sum();
```

I think the result of sum is a `long` as several integers can go past the max int value; you can always cast it if you are confident that it won't result in overflow.

It is not quite a one-liner at least as formatted above but arguably it fits in a single expression.

In case and element in the first list is null or if getAnotherObjList() returns a null you can support that by filtering out those cases:

```
long totalSum = listOfClassB.stream()
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .map(ClassB::getAnotherObjList)
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .mapToInt(List::size)
     .sum();
```

Comment: work thanks, will the above throw null exceptions if getAnotherObjList is null for any object? or will it just skip it

Comment: Yes it will. What you can do is filter out nulls, let me improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
listOfClassB.stream().map(ClassB::getAnotherObjList).flatMap(List::stream).count();
```

This is very concise and elegant.
If `ClassB::getAnotherObjList` does not return too many items performance would not be a problem.

Comment: This is also an elegant solution although is possibly less cpu efficient in practice... I wonder whether the flat-mapped stream implementation would realize that it does not need to unroll the individual lists to find out the final count since one can ask a Spliterator for the estimate (if not exact) count.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, using collectors:

```
int totalNo = listOfClassB.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.summingInt(classB -> classB.getAnotherObjList().size()));
```

An equivalent way, only with method references:

```
int totalNo = listOfClassB.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.mapping(
             ClassB::getAnotherObjList, 
             Collectors.summingInt(List::size)));
```

Or mapping in the stream instead of in the collector:

```
int totalNo = listOfClassB.stream()
    .map(ClassB::getAnotherObjList)
    .collect(Collectors.summingInt(List::size));
```